# How to create a random logical vector with specific numbers of TRUE / FALSE entries

Tags: r, vector

I would like to create a logical vector that has 10 rows, with each row randomly assigned either TRUE or FALSE.  However, I want there to only be 3 FALSE and 7 TRUE.

Example of desired outcome (logical vector with three randomly assigned FALSE entries and 7 randomly assigned TRUE entries):

```
> vector
 [1] "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "FALSE" "TRUE"  "FALSE" "FALSE" "TRUE" "TRUE" "TRUE" 
[10] "TRUE"
```

I can create a logical vector of size 10 that has TRUE or FALSE, but I don't know how to specify I want three FALSE entries and 7 TRUE entries.

```
vector <- sample(x = c("TRUE","FALSE"), size = 10, replace = TRUE)
```

This produces:

```
> train
 [1] "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "FALSE" "TRUE"  "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE"
[10] "TRUE"
```

Which has the incorrect number of TRUE and FALSE entries (4 TRUE and 6 FALSE).

Comment: `sample( c( rep(TRUE,7), rep(FALSE,3) ) )`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Wimpel and PKumar combined:

```
vector <- sample(c(rep(TRUE, 7), rep(FALSE, 3)), 10 ,replace = F)
```

Comment: `replace = FALSE` bij default, and `size = n`, also by defaut. So this code is longer than necessairy.. see `?sample`...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**Approach1 :**
Use `prob` parameter to give proportions for sample you select along with `replace=TRUE` in sample command. sample command doesn't guarantee the exact value of proportion, but for larger sample size it may give approximate proportions

```
x <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
sample(x,10 ,replace = TRUE, prob=c(.7, .3))
```

**Approach2:**
    For a perfect proportion:

```
rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), times= c(7,3)) ## In case you want to have perfect proportion
    #if someone wanted to randomly shuffle then one cas use:
     rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), times= c(7,3))[order(runif(10))]
```

**Output:**

> ```
> > sample(x,10 ,replace = T, prob=c(.7, .3))
>  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
>  [8]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> ```

**Output:**

```
rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), times= c(7,3))[order(runif(10))]
  [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
  [8]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: This would work with a small sample where n=10.  Is there a solution that would be more reliable for large samples (eg. n=1000, where the split had to be exact)?

Comment: some one should please explain the downvote ? It would also help me to know my mistake

Comment: I didn't downvote but `prob` assigns probability weights not proportions so this answer technically doesn't meet OPs stated requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to shuffle the positions of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, you can try the code below

```
res <- (v <- c(rep(TRUE, 7), rep(FALSE, 3)))[sample(seq(v))]
```

where `sample(seq(v))` generates random positions from `1` to `length(v)`